# PHP - how to put my Forum into a table column

Tags: php

I have an original index.php file about Forum installed at a HOST.
I need to make a table with two columns: one column for Ads and another column for the Forum.
When I use directly:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='20%'>";
    $dir = 'images/';
    if ($opendir = opendir($dir))
    {
        $file = 'lenovo-a1000.jpg';
        $type = 'image/jpeg';
        echo "<img src='$dir/$file' width='240' height='401'";
    }
echo "</td>";
echo "<td width='80%'>";
........
........ original code of the Forum;
........
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

it raises error messages, but the table appears;

Then to avoid error messages I decided to make two functions:

```
<?php
function tbl_open()
{
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width='20%'>";
      $dir = 'images/';
      if ($opendir = opendir($dir))
      {
        $file = 'lenovo-a1000.jpg';
        $type = 'image/jpeg';
        echo "<img src='$dir/$file' width='240' height='401'";
      }
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td width='80%'>";
}
........
........ original code of the Forum;
........
function tbl_close()
{
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Now there is not error messages, but the table does not appear.

How to solve my Problem ?

Comment: The actual error messages would be helpful.

Comment: And you don't even call the functions you created, how can the table appear?

Comment: I am absolutely beginner with PHP.

Comment: How to call functions ?

Comment: @finalist: `"How to call functions ?"` - The same way you're *already* calling a function, such as: `opendir($dir)`.  You might want to start with pretty much *any* introductory tutorial on PHP.  As for the error, as previously mentioned, we can't help you if you won't tell us what the error is.

Comment: The error messages are of this kind: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk10/2141550/www/sport7.cf/forum/index.php:11) in /srv/disk10/2141550/www/sport7.cf/forum/index.php on line 1106

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is not to make a table into a forum's index.php,  because this will raise warnings and errors about header().
My opinion now is the solution is to have a previous .php file which to start two iframes vertically suited FRAMES, for example (iframe width=80%) for the Forum and (iframe width=20%) for ads. I tested this - it works without any warnings and without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to echo HTML in PHP. Simply close the PHP tag, write yout HTML and open the PHP tag again when you want it again. EX:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width='20%'>
<?php
$dir = 'images/';
if ($opendir = opendir($dir))
{
    $file = 'lenovo-a1000.jpg';
    $type = 'image/jpeg'; ?>

    <img src='<?php echo $dir . $file ?>' width='240' height='401' />

<?php } ?>
</td>
<td width='80%'>

<?php
........
........ original code of the Forum;
........
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! @finalist Glad I could Help :) If you don't mind up voting my last comment so i get some rep that would be much appreciated

Comment: It is true, that at start the Forum works without warnings, but I so sorry,  when I did try to post an edited comment in my Forum there raised an error. So above method is not solved my problem with the Forum. I sorry.

Comment: When the forum starts => Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at www/sport7.cf/forum/index.php:1348) in www/FUDforum/include/core.inc on line 174; When I try to login => Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at www/sport7.cf/forum/index.php:1348) in www/sport7.cf/forum/theme/default/login.php on line 29.